# Export to KML (Portland) install fail on .dll load attempt

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, kml, windows-8.1

I downloaded the Export to KML extension for ArcMap and when I follow the instructions and run the batch file, the cmd comes up and as I hit a key to initiate the install, I get an error that reads:

"The module 'ExporttoKML.dll' was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with the error code 0x80004005"

OS: Windows 8.1
What I've tried: placing the ExporttoKML.dll file in my System32 folder and restarting; registering the .dll file using the cmd prompt line -

cd \windows\syswow64
regsvr32 c:\filename.dll

I was able to successfully register it, but the install error still comes up. Any thoughts?

ArcGIS version 10.2

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?  With an error like this I would check that I am meeting the system requirements and then probably just uninstall/reinstall ArcGIS for Desktop as an expedient to avoid wasting time trying to debug an install that may have been corrupted in any number of ways.

Comment: The extension might not be compatible with 8.1 as it was developed in 2012. The workaround was to click through the errors and then open Arc and open the Add-In window and navigate to the extension's .dll file and import from within Arc. It worked this way.

Answer (score 2):

I have only just realized that you are using an Export to KML extension and I do not know where that came from.

In any event, I would recommend that you use the tools which come out-of-the-box with ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop instead.

[Layer To KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000004n000000):

> This tool converts a feature or raster layer into a KML file
>   containing a translation of Esri geometries and symbology. This file
>   is compressed using ZIP compression, has a .kmz extension, and can be
>   read by any KML client including ArcGIS Explorer, ArcGlobe, and Google
>   Earth.

[Map To KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Map_To_KML/00120000004p000000/):

> This tool converts a map document into a KML file containing a
>   translation of Esri geometries and symbology. This file is compressed
>   using ZIP compression, will have a .kmz extension, and can be read by
>   any KML client including ArcGIS Explorer, ArcGlobe, and Google Earth.

To use [Windows 8.1 in a supported configuration](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//015100000002000000) be sure to install ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.